# Switching from Vim to Emacs - How to efficiently edit code

Tags: vim, emacs

Currently I try to switch from vim to emacs and have some difficulty while editing code. For most of the very simple vim keystrokes, I found an emacs version like simple movement

1. `h`, `j`, `k`, `l` are `C-b`, `C-n`, `C-p`, `C-f`
2. `w`, `b` are `M-f`, `M-b`
3. `I`, `A` are `C-a`, `C-e`
4. ...

but for some of the "more advanced" features I am used to, I am not sure what the emacs way of doing stuff is.

Here are some problems I have in my current workflow when I use emacs. 
Please show me how emacs people do this stuff (obviously **without using a vim emulation**) or what the alternative emacs-friendly workflow is.

#### Jumping with `f`

When I write something in vim and notice, I need to change something in that line I can use `f` to simply jump to it

```
int foo = caallFoo();
                     ^
```

In this case I would `Fad` to delete that 'a'. In emacs, I currently `M-b` and `C-f` until I find the character I want to edit. I try to use Ace Jump (which is a nice plugin) but for jumping in the line I currently am in this still feels bad.

So what is the emacs way of quickly navigating in a line without going crazy?

#### Navigating windows

My workflow often includes having multiple windows open in vim (lets say a file-browser, 4 code windows and a tagbar) and navigating works with `C-w h`, `C-w j`, `C-w k` and `C-w l`. When I press `C-w s` or `C-w v` a new window, it opens and relayouts all windows.

So far I've seen `C-x 2` and `C-x 3` in emacs to open new windows, but the size of them becomes smaller each time, as the newly created window and the focused window now share the space the focused window used to have. To navigate I only found `C-x o` which just cycles through the windows and does not let me pick a specific window to go to.

I've seen that some people use plugins to get a more sane multi-window workflow. 
Is there already some good window-navigation built into emacs or should I find a plugin that does the job for me? Or is my workflow with around 4-6 windows something I should not do in emacs.

#### Copy pasting, moving lines etc.

Something I like to do in code files is to create comments to visually mark certain sections.

```
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// SECTION
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
```

In vim I create it with something like `80a/<ESC>yyppklC` (80 times append a '/', copy that line and paste it two times, in the second line change everything after the second '/') and enter the name.

The creation of the first line is just as easy in emacs `C-u 80/` (80 times write '/') but copy-pasting would be something like `C-a C-SPC C-e M-w <ENTER> C-y <ENTER> C-y` (go to the beginning if the line, set a mark, go to the end of the line, copy everything, two times make a new line and paste). And then to write the section name `C-a C-p C-f C-f C-k` (go to the previous line, go to the beginning, go two chars right, delete until the end)

My emacs variant uses many keystrokes and is conceptually more complicated. If I could repeat the last action like in Vim, I would not have the problem with copy pasting (in vim `80a/<ESC>j.j.`) but in emacs repeating the last command would be navigating to the next line instead of "80 times insert '/'")

- How do I better copy/cut/paste whole lines? Or what is the alternative?
- How do I repeat the last action which is not a motion?

#### Moving the cursor

Something of a more simple movement I like to do while looking through code is moving the cursor with `C-d` and `C-u`. In emacs I only know `C-v` and `M-v` which moves the screen up and down and place the cursor at the beginning. How do I move the cursor down half a screen? Or alternativly how do I place the cursor in the middle/top/bottom of the screen like `H`, `M`, `L` do in vim?

Comment: Answer: Switch to VIM.  (Sorry, could not resist).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Jumping with f**

I'd do `C-r` `a` `RET` `DEL` That's not as good a vim. Vim really shines in this area.

**Navigating Windows**

My workflow is to have two windows, that leaves me with `C-x o` always doing what I want.

I do a lot more buffer switching and not much window navigation. I don't try to get buffers in particular windows.

I mult task by task switching, not looking at multiple windows at the same time, you might be different. I use helm and use an symbolic-label non-visual approach. It goes like this, I have the feeling that I need to something else, I think the words related to it, I hit `C-x b`, I type the words, the thing is at the top of helm-minibuffer.

You can probably find a multi window workflow that will fit your style.

**Copy pasting, moving lines etc.**

There's kill-whole-line bound to `C-S-backspace`.

`c-u 80 / C-S-backspace // SECTION C-y`

I don't know how to repeat the last action that is not a motion. I often record a macro even for short things I'm going to use twice.

**Moving the Cursor**

`C-l` will call recenter-top-bottom. This will cycle through those positions.

Good luck.

Comment: Have you tried evil-mode? Evil-mode is vi bindings for Emacs.

Comment: C-x z looks is interesting. But is does repeat commands that are motions.

Comment: @McNisse The original poster specifically asked for "solutions without using a vim emulation".  I personally have not tried evil.

Answer (score 0):

First, you should forget Vi(m). they have different *design philosophy*.

Edit code vim is faster than emacs(`hjkl` faster than `C-n/p/b/f`), but emacs advocate *effective edit*. such as:

### Moving the cursor/Jump

[ace-jump-mode](https://github.com/winterTTr/ace-jump-mode) very nice. I bind jump mode to `F9`.

```
(define-key global-map (kbd "<f9>") 'ace-jump-mode)
```

1. press `F9`
2. jump to screen anywhere with a word start `char`
3. input char index

### Navigating Window

- `C-x 3` vertical split frame
- `C-x 2` horizontal split frame
- `C-x 1` close other frame except current(not close file)
- `C-x 0` close current frame

I think emacs split window is better than vim(`:split`), but switch window bother than vim (`C-x o`). You can use [emacs-winum](https://github.com/deb0ch/emacs-winum):

```lisp
(setq winum-keymap
    (let ((map (make-sparse-keymap)))
      (define-key map (kbd "C-c `") 'winum-select-window-by-number)
      (define-key map (kbd "M-0") 'winum-select-window-0-or-10)
      (define-key map (kbd "M-1") 'winum-select-window-1)
      (define-key map (kbd "M-2") 'winum-select-window-2)
      (define-key map (kbd "M-3") 'winum-select-window-3)
      (define-key map (kbd "M-4") 'winum-select-window-4)
      (define-key map (kbd "M-5") 'winum-select-window-5)
      (define-key map (kbd "M-6") 'winum-select-window-6)
      (define-key map (kbd "M-7") 'winum-select-window-7)
      (define-key map (kbd "M-8") 'winum-select-window-8)
      map))
```

switch frame by `Meta + 0/1/2/3 ...`, very convenient.

I also recommend [company](https://github.com/company-mode/company-mode) and [helm](https://github.com/emacs-helm/helm)/[ivy](https://github.com/abo-abo/swiper)

---

Emacs work like IDE, heavy; Vim like editor, lightweight.

Answer (score 0):

I use both vim and emacs and if you are able to figure out emacs it really can do well.

1. avy-goto-char avy-goto-char-2 avy-goto-line
2. (setq avy-all-windows) will allow the above commands to navigate anywhere, even navigate windows.
3. check out how doom emacs handles windows and everything else. its basically a excellently configured emacs if you ignore the evil parts. learn how to best use emacs by how others use it, and doom is a good reference.
4. your other questions you can answer yourself as you learn